# angular ssl certificate ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: angular, spring, ssl, https, certificate

1. I bought valid SSL certificate for my website, however when I serve angular with it at https://localhost:4200/ I still have the browser page warning the certificate is invalid. The details of the certificate seems correct though on that page.
   is this an expected behaviour?

   "start": "ng serve --ssl true --ssl-key ssl/cert.key --ssl-cert ssl/cert.crt",

NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
Subject: m%%%%%%%%%.io

Issuer: Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA

Expires on: 3 Oct 2022

Current date: 2 Jul 2020

PEM encoded chain:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----

2. I came to look at it as I previously simply uploaded my website files generated through `ng build -- prod` into the server and try to login but I received `443/login net::ERR_CERT_INVALID`
   https is showing with a lock but POST is being denied

All this is rather confusing for me. I received two files from the CA provider
**Your PositiveSSL Multi-Domain Certificate - cert.crt**
**Your Apache "bundle" file - cert.ca-bundle**

if that is for any help the server is spring and the details are attached below.
Can someone please shed some lights?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService;
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public SecurityConfiguration(UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userPrincipalDetailsService = userPrincipalDetailsService;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
                .cors().
                and()
                .csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), this.userRepository))
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userPrincipalDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*" ));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "x-auth-token"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to have the hostname as one of the subjectAltName in the certificates. If it's only present in the common name you'll get that error. Just look at the cert for this site.

Answer (score 0):

1. The issue which I had with ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID I think can be discarded as this is only in a dev environment for localhost
2. The issue which I had with ERR_CERT_INVALID was that the spring server had an incorrect keystore file generated `server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystoref.p12`

Answer (score 0):

"`when I serve angular with it at https://localhost:4200/`"

Because you have to use a FQDN

More info here: https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-a-fully-qualified-domain-name/

Answer (score 0):

**we are using gRPC API's with envoyproxy**

replace your server address by domain name don't use 192.xx.xx.122:443(wrong),
this.user_login_grpc = new QcfEmployeeDataClient('192.xx.xx.122:443');

instead use domain name example (https://example.com) its resolve my issue.
**this.login_grpc = new userClient('https://backend-domain.com');**